# increment document id by timestamp in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My cloud firestore database has an "orders" collection and in HTML I have a 'save' button to `add` document(s) into that "orders" collection upon clicking. Now, using `add` will assign auto-generated ID for each document.

What if I want to customise such ID by **timestamp**? So that the document created yesterday will be assigned an index as '1', and the following document created will be '2', etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not compatible with the way Cloud Firestore was designed.  Firestore will not assign monotonically increasing numbers for document IDs.  This just doesn't scale massively as required by Firestore and would introduce performance bottlenecks.

If you want to be able to sort documents by timestamp, the best strategy is to add a timestamp field to each document, then use that field in an ordered query.

Note that you could try to write a lot of code to get this done the way you want, but you are MUCH better off accepting the random IDs and using fields to filter and order data.

Answer (score 1):

in some case, when you need to save several docs in different collection due to an event occurs, it's better to same all docs with same id in different collections with single firestore server's timestamp. you get the timestamp like below:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const ts = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis().toString()
```

by doing this, when you need to read all those docs, you only need to query once to get timestamp, then read all other doc by timestamp directly.
it should be faster than query the timestamp inside document fields for each collections